# RAID 1 with 3 disks and frequent disk swap

Tags: network-attached-storage, raid1

We want to apply RAID 1 in a NAS device with 2 disks to store backups. Since the data is important, we would like to keep one disk out of the office. So, we buy an additional disk to exchange with a disk in the array once per week, and keep one safe somewhere else. Then, the replaced disk in the array get synchronized with the other disk.

- Is it a good and suitable scheme?
- When an outdated disk is replaced in the array, how synchronization works? which disk is updated? Is there any order in RAID 1, or just the replaced new disk which is added to the array synchronized with the other disk which was already in the array?

Comment: Depending on the size of the disks, the synkronization could take days or in extreme cases - weeks. That method creates also unnecessary load on the disks.
Question, not invest in a NAS where you can "mirror" the content completly to another NAS?

Comment: I know people who are doing it that way and they are happy. Note that if you have only 1 more disk for rotation then `all` disks may be in the same room once per week. Better use at least 2 more disks. One is _always_ at home .

Comment: @Orphans: Rebuild time may be not as bad if bitmaps are enabled `mdadm --grow --bitmap=internal /dev/md0`

Comment: @rudimeier: Is it also possible to enable bitmaps on a NAS device like WD My Cloud DL2100?

Comment: BTW if possible you could also consider to have 2 NAS boxes both configured for backup storage. Exchange them once per week. Both boxes contain an independent backup history. No rebuild times, maybe you don't even need raid.

Comment: @rudimeier why do things more complicated? Only time wasting and the risk for anyone messing it up is alot higher if they are going to tamper with it.

Comment: @Orphans I simply thought about my own backup server. It would take me 20 minutes to clone the whole machine. Both clones could run simultaneously. No problems if one of them would have 1 week downtime. So exchanging both boxes once per week would be much easier for me than exchanging HDs.

Comment: @rudimeier Your own personal? I got the impression that Masood wanted a solution for his company. So no, it is not a good solution. And depending on the NAS (not server) they have, it synch could actually day many hours or days.

Comment: @Orphans: It's our companies backup. NAS or server what is the difference? Our box is pulling the backups daily via ssh. It wakes up only at night. Very simple and robust setup. During the day it's off and could be replaced without problems.

Comment: @Masood, If the data is that important, why not implement a more comprehensive backup solution that doesn't involve rotating disks and always guarantees that at least one copy of the data is off site.  There are many ways and products to accomplish tasks like this depending on OS and network.

Answer (score 0):

It should work but it is not effective.
Many NAS can synchronize to USB disk with push of button or command at his webpage. You can also synchronize with rsync or other this type software via workstation if synchronisation via NAS is not possible.
You also should consider backup via internet to remote site. In most cases most date don't change frequency so you don't need to transfer many data per day. But it need more check to be sure.